# How to pass parameters from controller in ror?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to show two columns from employee attendance table which is day and present , but unable to show -

Here is my show page -

```
<div class="box box-default">
<div class="box-header with-border">
<h3 class="box-title">Holiday Setup</h3>
</div><!-- /.box-header -->
<div class="box-body">
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Day</th>  
      <th>Present</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @employee_attendances.each do |employee_attendance| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= employee_attendance.day %></td>
          <td><%= employee_attendance.present %></td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Controller code -

```
def holiday_setup
  @day = params[:day]
  @employee_attendances = EmployeeAttendance.where(present: 'H',day: @day)
end
```

Comment: *but unable to show* Do you get any error?

Comment: no .. but when i debug day gives nil .

Comment: Do you have anything in `params[:day]`?

Comment: Then `@day` is `nil`. Inspect the `params[:day]` and tell me what do you get

Comment: yes day consist date . In table day column has date .

Comment: What is the query that goes for ```EmployeeAttendance.where(present: 'H',day: @day)``` in server logs...

Comment: 15-08-2017 | H   these two things show come on page .

Comment: @VamsiKrishna SELECT `employee_attendances`.* FROM `employee_attendances` WHERE `employee_attendances`.`present` = 'H'

Comment: @AnubhiGolechha please post results of  `@employee_attendances`

Comment: The day related where cond is not there in the select query...Did you add the ```day: @day``` just now

Comment: than how i can write where condition so that i get day also .

Comment: Error solved i replaced where query from  @employee_attendances = EmployeeAttendance.where(present: 'H') now showing data .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error solved i replaced where query from @employee_attendances = EmployeeAttendance.where(present: 'H') now showing data